# How do I get this function to loop? Python

Tags: python

So I want the code to to pretty much add the sum of all the numbers in the list until the length of the list is meet. Every even number gets divided with 2...

Right now it only returns the first number in the list.

Can anyone here help?

```
lista = [8,2,3,4,10,6]
def suma2(lista):
    i = 0
    suma = 0
    while i <= len(lista):
          if (lista[i] %2 == 0):
               suma = suma + lista[i]/2
         else:
             suma = suma + lista[i]
         i = i + 1

         return suma
```

Comment: move return suma one tab back, and change the while condition to < and not <=

Comment: Oh god of course thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement is breaking out of the `function` - stopping the `loop`. You just need to indent it back by one...

You also need to change the less than or equal (`<=`) sign to just a less than (`<`) one. This is because you are looping *up to* the length of the `list`. If you allow `i` to reach the length, because Python `lists` are indexed from `0`, this will try and access a value one after the end which will throw an `error`!

The code after correcting theses two things would look something like:

```
lista = [8,2,3,4,10,6]
def suma2(lista):
    i = 0
    suma = 0
    while i < len(lista):
          if (lista[i] %2 == 0):
               suma = suma + lista[i]/2
         else:
             suma = suma + lista[i]
         i = i + 1

    return suma
```

To improve the `code`, you could replace the `while` loop with a `for` loop which `iterates` through the items in `lista`. This would be a better approach as you never use the variable `i` apart from accessing the `list`, so it would make more sense to just `loop` through the `elements` in `lista` and assign each `element` to a variable (not the indexes)...

The code for doing that would look something like (I also used `+=` instead of how you had it, to make the code neater):

```
lista = [8,2,3,4,10,6]
def suma2(lista):
    suma = 0
    for e in lista:
          if (e % 2 == 0):
               suma += e/2
         else:
             suma += e

    return suma
```

See how it's much neater now? Hope this helps!